# Cross-platform way to kill a process in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have a method which kills a process by name, but only works in Windows since I use Windows API. I am currently converting my code to run in another OS, so I am looking for a cross-platform way.

Is there any method in the boost library that kills a process by name? I have not found it, and I am not able to find a cross-platform solution in the Web.

Many thanks,

Comment: There isn't one in boost, so you'll have to break it into two smaller tasks - 1. finding the process by name and then 2. sending a signal to the process to terminate it. If you have any control of the code in the remote process, it would be better arranging an IPC mechanism to close the remote process cleanly

Comment: Many platforms don't have process names, and some don't have processes - so no, there's no cross-platform way to kill a process by name.